# Checking if dates in one set are within the bounds of another set in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Please, how can I check if the dates in one column of an Excel table are within the bounds of another set of dates in a different column of a separate table? I need a formula or method to identify the matches.

Excel table 1 :
[image]

Excel table 2 : Every day of the year with sunrise and sunset times
[image]

thanks

I didn't find a solution after several tests (`IFS`, `VLOOKUP`, ...)

Comment: What would be the expected result?

Comment: If you provide sample data via [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) (read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16578424) for an explanation) it is easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I just got it done with such a formula:

```
=OR(AND(A2>=Sheet2!A$2;A2<=Sheet2!B$2);AND(A2>=Sheet2!A$3;A2<=Sheet2!B$3);AND(A2>=Sheet2!A$4;A2<=Sheet2!B$4);AND(A2>=Sheet2!A$5;A2<=Sheet2!B$5))
```

A bit clearer:

```
=OR(AND(A2>=Sheet2!A$2;A2<=Sheet2!B$2);
    AND(A2>=Sheet2!A$3;A2<=Sheet2!B$3);
    AND(A2>=Sheet2!A$4;A2<=Sheet2!B$4);
    AND(A2>=Sheet2!A$5;A2<=Sheet2!B$5))
```

Comment: Thank you, 
I'm looking for a way not to do this for 365 lines, the risk of error and I don't even know if there isn't a limited volume.